# How to get mod_security to log all POST data?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

I currently have a CentOS system that is successfully logging relevant mod_security actions to the audit log file. The following is my configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleEngine On
  SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
  SecAuditLog /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log
  SecDebugLog /var/log/httpd/modsec_debug.log
  SecDebugLogLevel 0
  SecRequestBodyAccess On
  SecDataDir /tmp
  SecTmpDir /tmp
  SecPcreMatchLimit 250000
  SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 250000
</IfModule>
```

This logs all actions where mod_security intercepts/blocks the request because of the `SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly` setting.

However, I would like it to additionally log all POST data that is submitted to the server (regardless of the status). I could achieve this by setting `SecAuditEngine On` but this logs all GET and POST data which is overkill. I would basically like to omit all GET data unless the request was intercepted.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Note: this will expose things like passwords in plain-text. If your system is at all sensitive (god forbid it process credit cards) this may be an unacceptable risk.

Comment: We are looking to determine where/how malware is being uploaded, so we want to see how file X was uploaded to the server. Do you have a suggestion how to do this without exposing sensitive information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a rule which turns on the `AuditEngine` for `POST` requests.

Something like this (untested):

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "POST" "id:1000,phase:2,ctl:auditEngine=On,nolog,pass"
```

Ctl actions only affect the current request so afterwards it will reset back to RelevantOnly for the next request.

You can also create `Sanitise` rules to ensure sensitive data like passwords and credit card data is masked before logging. See here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#sanitiseArg