# mod_security: How to log POST requests for specific URI ONLY?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, mod-security

I am currently running Apache 2.4.25 on Debian 9.8. I'm trying to set up mod_security to log POST request payloads for a specific URI. I have several API on a Debian server and I have to log all of them except 2.
I tried to log only one URI for testing but it seems that the rules I tried doesn't work.

I started by following [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/753261/mod-security-how-to-log-post-requests-for-specific-uri) but it seems it doesn't work.
Every calls are logged. Even if I comment the two SecRule lines, it still log every call.

My config :

```
 # On active le module.
SecRuleEngine On
SecAuditEngine On
# On lui donne un fichier de log.
SecAuditLog /var/log/httpd/website-audit.log
# On l'autorise à accéder au corps des requêtes.
SecRequestBodyAccess on
SecAuditLogParts ABCDEFGHIJZ

# On configure une action par défaut.
SecDefaultAction "nolog,noauditlog,allow,phase:2"

# On définit une règle qui nous permet de logger le contenu des requêtes POST
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" "chain,allow,phase:2,id:13"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@streq /api/ICM/SendMessage" "auditlog"
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most mod_security settings can be activated and /or disabled for any specific scope in Apache, by including them in a particular  `<VirtualHost> ..` or `<Location ...>` or `<Directory ...>` block but some are restricted and cannot be changed / set in such a way. See https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#configuration-directives That means that maybe some settings are configured or need to be in for instance a .htaccess , specific VirtualHost or other file than what you are editing

Comment: Thanks but the config file is activated. If I set `SecRuleEngine Off`, logs are desactivated.
With `SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "^POST$" "chain,deny,phase:2,id:13"`, all calls are denied. 
So, I don't think the problem is the activation of this config file.

Comment: SecAuditEngine Off
must be Off otherwise all actions will be logged. However, since this is Off, there is none log. Why ? "auditlog" need any configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!@streq POST" "allow,phase:1,id:13,ctl:auditEngine=Off"
```

Please note for the [reference](http://SecRule%20REQUEST_METHOD):

*If the SecAuditEngine is set to On, **all of the transactions will be logged**. If it is **set to RelevantOnly**, then you can control the logging with the noauditlog action.*

So, this would be the another solution.

*The noauditlog action affects only the current rule. If you prevent audit logging in one rule only, a match in another rule will still cause audit logging to take place. If you want to prevent audit logging from taking place, regardless of whether any rule matches, use ctl:auditEngine=Off.*

But IMHO the `ctl` action above is more clear.